# If a tab has the same name as a card, should the card heading be removed?

Tags: design-patterns, tabs, material-design, cards

I am using material design concept. I have tabs and within each tab are cards with headings and content. Sometimes there are 4+ cards inside each tab, sometimes there is only 1 card.

I understand that if there are multiple cards, every card within each tab should have a separate heading.

If there is only 1 card within the tab: does the card need a heading? Or is the name of the tab enough?

Comment: Could you display some design or wireframe?

Answer (score 2):

Your tabs should be your top level navigation; and should be as general as you can make them (So you can organize your content in finer layers like in Cards, Lists, etc). In your situation; using cards as your next layer of refinement in content organization; I would personally say keep it consistent with the other tabs - and have the heading on all the cards; regardless of the content on that page.

I also want to iterate that not every tab has to have content within a card; some elements of information are better displayed as a List, or Grids. Make sure that the content your populating on the tabs suits the usage of cards:

> A card is a sheet of material that serves as an entry point to more
>   detailed information.

Hope this helps!

*Source:*
*https://material.io/guidelines/components/cards.html*

Comment: In general, I'd echo consistency. If the content _on_ the card moves up or down (because the card sometimes has its own title and sometimes not) then this can be very annoying. Also, in many cases, the space available in a tab may not be enough to show a full title, whereas the card's title can do.